# Maven error during importing maven projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm facing below error when I tried to import a spring boot maven project into eclipse.

An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.(Unknown Source)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *

1 error

I've tried importing the same project in multiple versions of eclipse and still the result is same. Please guide me.

Comment: Which Java version do you use?

Comment: Adding to the other question, it might be useful to know all the details you're not specifying, like Java version, Eclipse version(s), platform.